# Error and warning messages in VSCode while running Next.js with Turbopack: Hidden paths and unresolved paths

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, turbopack

Error and warning messages in VSCode while running Next.js with Turbopack: Hidden paths and unresolved paths

I'm running a Next.js application with Turbopack, and I'm encountering some error and warning messages in Visual Studio Code (VSCode) during development.

When I run npm run dev to start the development server, the following messages appear in the VSCode output panel:

```
>>> TURBOPACK (beta)

Thank you for trying Next.js v13 with Turbopack! As a reminder,
Turbopack is currently in beta and not yet ready for production.
We appreciate your ongoing support as we work to make it ready
for everyone.

Learn more about Next.js v13 and Turbopack: https://nextjs.link/with-turbopack
Please direct feedback to: https://nextjs.link/turbopack-feedback

ready - started server on [::]:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
warning - [parse] ... [1 paths] are hidden, run with --show-all to show them
event - 8 requests (GET /, ...) 5213ms
event - 23 requests (GET /images/blog.png, ...) 730ms
event - 16 requests (GET /turbopack-hmr, ...) 964ms
error - [resolve]
  ... [3 paths] are hidden, run with --show-all to show them
warning -
  [parse]
    ... [6 paths] are hidden, run with --show-all to show them
  [resolve]
    ... [1 paths] are hidden, run with --show-all to show them
```

I have tried running the server with the --show-all flag as suggested in the warning and error messages, but nothing seems to happen.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me understand and resolve these error and warning messages. Thank you for your assistance!